# ¿Como llenar un vector con valores que cumplan una condición de números random?

Tags: c++, vectores

Estoy haciendo este ejercicio para la facultad sobre arreglos. Logré cumplir con las primeras condiciones pero se me dificulta la última. El vector continúa sacando números random y evaluando la condición hasta que la variable i alcanza la cantidad_posiciones ingresada por teclado pero necesito que el vector continúe llenándose de valores hasta que alcance la cantidad de posiciones ingresada. Dejo el código y la consigna. Muchas Gracias!!

Debe generar un vector de N posiciones con números obtenidos al azar entre 1 y C con las siguientes restricciones:

- el vector debe ir llenándose en orden desde la posición 1 hasta la N.
- los números obtenidos podrán almacenarse si dicho número es mayor al almacenado en la posición anterior.
- los números obtenidos podrán almacenarse sólo si permiten que el vector pueda ser llenado en su totalidad (sin pasar el valor C en la posición N).

Los valores de N y C se ingresan al inicio.

```
  #include <time.h>
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int cantidad_posiciones, limite_superior, numeros_aleatoreos[100], numeros;
    
    cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad de posiciones del vector."<<endl;
    cout<<"(Las mismas deberan ser menores a 100) : ";
    cin>>cantidad_posiciones;
    cout<<"Ingrese el limite superior para los numeros aleatoreos: ";
    cin>>limite_superior;
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    numeros_aleatoreos[0] = 0;
    int cont=1;
    
    
    for(int i=1;i<=cantidad_posiciones;i++){
        numeros = 1 + rand()%limite_superior;
        cout<<numeros<<endl;
        if(numeros>numeros_aleatoreos[cont-1]){
            numeros_aleatoreos[cont]= numeros;
            cout<<cont<<". "<<numeros_aleatoreos[cont]<<endl;
            cont++;
        }
    }
            
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás complicándote de más: es mucho más costoso generar números al azar y esperar que por azar coincidan con las restricciones que generar números al azar y ajustarlos para que se ajusten a las restricciones.

Estas restricciones pueden resumirse en:

- Números al azar entre A y Z (ambos no incluídos) sin repeticiones.
- Los números están ordenados ascendentemente (A < B < C ... < Z).
- La cantidad de números está prefijada.

Mi acercamiento a estas limitaciones sería generar una colección de incrementos porcentuales cuyo total sea aproximadamente 100. Para eso generamos los números y los normalizamos sobre 100:

```
random_device device;
mt19937 generador(device());
uniform_int_distribution<> distribucion(1, 1000);

cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de posiciones del vector.\n";
int cantidad_posiciones;
cin >> cantidad_posiciones;

vector<int> numeros_aleatoreos(cantidad_posiciones);

// Generar numeros
int total = 0;
for (auto &numero : numeros_aleatoreos)
    total += (numero = distribucion(generador));

// Normalizar sobre 100
for (auto &numero : numeros_aleatoreos)
    numero = (numero = ((numero * 100) / total)) ? numero : 1;
```

Una vez tenemos esto, basta con (empezando desde la segunda posición):

1. Calcular el % del total de números y sumarlo al número anterior.
2. Guardarlo en la posición siguiente.
3. Repetir hasta calcular todos los números.

Por ejemplo, con un límite superior de 200 y tomando 10 números, suponiendo que los percentiles generados sean: 11, 3, 6, 12, 3, 1, 18, 18, 18, 5.

- 1r número `11`.
- 2º número 11 + (3% de 200) = `17`.
- 3º número 17 + (6% de 200) = `29`.
- 4º número 29 + (12% de 200) = `53`.
- 5º número 53 + (3% de 200) = `59`.
- 6º número 59 + (1% de 200) = `61`.
- 7º número 61 + (18% de 200) = `97`.
- 8º número 97 + (18% de 200) = `133`.
- 9º número 133 + (18% de 200) = `169`.
- 10º  número 169 + (5% de 200) = `179`.

```
int limite_superior = 0;
cout << "Ingrese el limite superior para los numeros aleatoreos: ";
cin >> limite_superior;

for (int indice = 1; indice != cantidad_posiciones; ++indice)
    numeros_aleatoreos[indice] = numeros_aleatoreos[indice - 1] + ((limite_superior * numeros_aleatoreos[indice]) / 100);

for (auto &numero : numeros_aleatoreos)
    cout << numero << ' ';
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZPPbtQwEMbP8VMMi2jjLmUTOKC2STgiLn0BWEXGMauRHDvynx5APPsyXm82tGylcortmfFvvm8cOU3XUguz2@9fo5E6DgoatD44JcaOLWdOmME@OnlQMljXMYYmwCjQlJz9YkX0aHZgxKj8JKQCH4Y7xopc3w/qAekwf@5YMYb65ubDR9gpo5wYrCtzqOScotHgD@vGngj9gNQUfo8BrWk6mLeStmX9FuqqqngCSRsDNA2svpidU16BFiCFCTiIgbgwWY@pSHnaacgq3n0zK@IlJXNuvyRSRKKBrjsfBFbkWxqq78DEUTnre6GVoENlfXmm7NDrZgOfD8LdXJV7CDYIDS1URCYDoBQxWLjIOXB7BsFZUeSqdQvlMbF97NLJYz7D78lcofEn8QW8@R/WibCwynl5lYbBYZNlcA6f4HRbnchJosYRg@p9nJRDwmax/wyPJpQz4ZQ5CSdAWz93Bktnt7BaZvWEkMAHfYmOZkjPsKV@5vWr9ux0Yb3OCYvqv734moNbuurZIFxDvYU1GfRU9NXzRdtkYH180y@fy2zgMY1Wl3B5@P9UiM4kk3/v93XF3lcV@wM)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias!! La verdad no se me había ocurrido pensarlo de esa manera. Me cuesta entender un poco el código pero voy a probar aplicarlo al  ejercicio. Saludos!